# R effects and car packages crash R

Tags: r, osx-yosemite

Operating System:  OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

I can no longer run the "car" or "effects" packages without taking down R. I updated to the most recent package versions (2.1.1 for car and 3.0.6 for effects) including dependencies but this did not make any difference.

Appreciate any help

Thanks
Scott

I get the following message:

```
> library(effects)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x318, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 4: asNamespace(ns)
 5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 6: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 7: asNamespace(ns)
 8: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 9: loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))
10: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
11: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
12: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
13: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
14: try({    ns <- loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
15: library(effects)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Comment: Hah, `car` crashes. Sorry, not helpful. It works fine for me on El Capitan, though.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on El Cap with those R and package versions while running in the R.app GUI. I suggest that you redo the installation of effects using `dependencies=TRUE`.

Comment: I have tried 'install.packages("car",dependencies=TRUE)'  but made no difference.

Comment: I contacted the package maintainer and he is not real knowledgable enough with MACs to troubleshoot the problem. Following his advice I loaded each of the packages in the Imports list.  R crashes when loading pbkrst and lme4.  Not sure where to go from here.